# how to avoid accumulation when sending the variable from one batch file to other

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a program to take data from one file and modify it and again save it in the same file
when I am executing the program the variable with the same name is getting accumulated in the file.

how to make it overite the variable instead of accumulating?

**base code**

```
@echo off
call data.bat
echo variable1 (from data.bat) = %variable1%
echo variable2 (from data.bat) = %variable2%
pause
call :Display
rem IMPORTANT! This file MUST end with GOTO :EOF!
pause
set /a variable2=variable2/2
@echo SET variable2=%variable2%>>data.bat
goto :EOF
pause
```

**data file**

```
set variable1=22    
SET variable2=99
```

Comment: `cmd` can either overwrite a file (from the very start) or append to it (at the very end).. There are no methods to (over)write a specific line. You will have to read and rewrite the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

This line incorrectly reports (not var3)

```
echo variable3 (from data.bat) = %variable2%
```

This line sets the value of `variable2` to "the current value of a variable named `echo variable3`" + "/2"

```
SET variable2=%echo variable3%/2
```

Since `echo variable3` is probably not set, batch sets `variable2` to `/2` and records that value as requested.

So - we're guessing what you intended to do. Perhaps `variable3` is set in your unpublished routine `display`.

If you had intended to override the setting of `variable2` in your `data.bat` file with - at a guess, half its value, then the correct batch line would be

```
set /a variable2=variable2/2
```

or

```
set /a variable2=%variable2%/2
```

which are equivalent.

So what `variable3` has to do with the problem is a mystery. Telling us what you expected to happen would reduce the guesswork required.